# AngularJS - when checkbox is checked i want to print what i've checked

Tags: angularjs

I need help with: 
AngularJS - when checkbox is checked i want to print what i've checked.

Here is the preview. I want to sum those prices when i click on each of them.

```
Check the jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDbBJ/

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hUUko?p=preview)

The main idea is use ng-click to catch which one is checked and sum it up in the mainctrl $scope

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sum = 0;
  $scope.Selected = function (val,smartphone){
    if(val){      
      $scope.sum += parseInt(smartphone.price,10);
    }else{
      $scope.sum -= parseInt(smartphone.price,10);
    }

  };
});
```